# Create a custom template for a user story in Rallydev

Tags: rally

Is there a way to create a pre-populated notes field when creating a user story in Rally?  I want to define a standard format for my team to use and they would just need to fill in the requested fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is a popular feature request. Some customers with this need setup their "template" stories pre-populated with the requisite data, and leave them un-scheduled, and ranked so they appear at the top of the backlog. Then they make copies of the template stories when creating new stories to write and then pull into sprints.

Answer (score 0):

Rally (now CA Agile Central) now has support for defining templates for the Description field and it can be shared with other users, but as an experimental "Labs" feature. It is useable and works for me. To see the Lab features and try this out, click on your profile icon in the top right, choose My Settings, and click on the Labs link in the top bar. The feature is called Rich Text Template Sharing. Once you enable it, you should see a Templates link in the New Story creation dialog for the Description field.